# Highcharts graph not rendering in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, highcharts

I am trying to render a graph by calling a function. The chart is not rendering in my jsp page, but when I test the exact same code in JSFiddle, it works.

I have the following libraries also:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

The following script tag contains the function that creates the chart:

```
<script>
    function drawChart(xAxis, yAxis, title, type ) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: type
        },
        title: {
            text: title
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: xAxis
            },

            type: 'category',
        },
        yAxis:{
            title: {
                text: yAxis,
            },
        },

        series: [{
           data: [{
            x: 100,
            y: 50
        }],
      }]
    })
}
</script>
```

I also have a separate div tag which calls this function as such:

```
<script>drawChart("test1", "test2", "test3", "column");</script>
```

And a div tag for the chart:

```
<div id="container" style="width:80%; height:400px; width: 300px;"> </div>
```

Below is a JSFiddle link which shows my chart rendering with the values I pass in.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/6645/

I'm not sure where I am going wrong. Nothing seems obvious to me. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that my script tags are within the head tag.

EDIT: I have updated my JSFiddle to show x and y values. My issue is nothing renders on my JSP and I don't know why.

EDIT: This has now been fixed. The highcharts library depends on a jquery library so I added the following above the highcharts library:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Turns out JSFiddle doesn't require you to reference a jquery library so it worked fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working in JSFiddle and not my JSP as my JSP was missing the jquery library, which the highcharts library depends upon. It turns out that JSFiddle does not need you to reference the jquery library as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You  have written series in wrong manner

```
series: [{
            name: 'Population',
            data: [
                ['Shanghai', 23.7],
                ['Lagos', 16.1],
                ['Istanbul', 14.2],
                ['Karachi', 14.0],
                ['Mumbai', 12.5],
                ['Moscow', 12.1],
                ['São Paulo', 11.8],
                ['Beijing', 11.7],
                ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
                ['Delhi', 11.1],
                ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
                ['Seoul', 10.4],
                ['Jakarta', 10.0],
                ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
                ['Tianjin', 9.3],
                ['Tokyo', 9.0],
                ['Cairo', 8.9],
                ['Dhaka', 8.9],
                ['Mexico City', 8.9],
                ['Lima', 8.9]
            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
```

Above code may help you

Answer (score 0):

change series parameter and put in array 
try this way

```
function drawChart(xAxis, yAxis, title, type ) {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: title
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: xAxis
        },

        type: 'category',
    },
    yAxis:{
        title: {
            text: yAxis,
        },
    },

    series: [{
        data:[
  ['x', 100],
        ['y', 50]
  ]
    }],

})
```

}

drawChart("test1", "test2", "test3", "column");

Comment: Thanks for your response. That hasn't changed things at all. It still doesn't render for some unknown reason.

Comment: Please read my original question. My issue is that nothing is rendering on my JSP page but does render something on JSFiddle.

Comment: I have checked your code in JSFiddle that you have already posted

Comment: My example doesn't have the x and y values, I agree with that. But my issue is my JSP. Not even your code will render in my JSP. At least my code shows the x and y titles in the js fiddle. I get a blank page in my JSP.

Comment: I've updated my JSFiddle to reflect the x and y values. Unfortunately that's not the issue. My JSP is behaving weird o.O

Comment: make sure highchart.js is loaded by examining network tab in developer tool